# ical allday events starts at +01:00

Tags: php, icalendar

I'm trying to export a calender from my database to an ical-file using php.

It works fine except for one thing: all events gets set to start at 01:00 and not 00:00. It might have something to do with winter/summertime. I've set the timezone (that changed the starttime from 02:00 to 01:00

**php-code**

```
$ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\nMETHOD:PUBLISH VERSION:2.0\r\n";
$ical .= "PRODID:-//SYKL.no//Norsk Rittkalender//NO\r\n";
$ical .= "BEGIN:VTIMEZONE\r\nTZID:Europe/Oslo\r\nEND:VTIMEZONE\r\n";
foreach($kalender as $k) {
if($k['typeritt']!="3") {
$ical .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\nSUMMARY: " . strtoupper($k['navn']) . "\r\n";
$ical .= "UID: " . $k['rittresultatid'] . "\r\n";
$ical .=  "DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Oslo:" . date('Ymd', strtotime($k['startdato'])) . "T000000\r\n";
$ical .= "DTEND;TZID=Europe/Oslo: " . date('Ymd', strtotime($k['sluttdato'])) . "T000000" ."\r\n";
$ical .= "END:VEVENT\r\n"; }
}
$ical .= "END:VCALENDAR";

$filename="ical.ics";
header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
echo utf8_encode($ical);
```

Thanks in advance!

the $kalender array uses some norwegian

**norwegian for dummies:**

```
navn = name
rittresultatid = ID
startdato = start date
sluttdato = end date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you see this behavior because your `VTIMEZONE` doesn't specify any time zone offsets (a valid `VTIMEZONE` object must contain at least one `STANDARD` or `DAYLIGHT` component). Try to include a valid `VTIMEZONE` (see [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.5)) or specify your date times in UTC.

Optionally make your event "all-day" by omitting any time information like so:

```
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160303
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160304
```